# The given path's format is not supported while routing in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to implement a URL redirect to redirect all request to a URL for e.g. like `www.myweb.com/201` to `www.myweb.com/201/my-blog-title`:

The code I have is below.

In controller:

```
public ActionResult Post(int pId){
...
    string urlPostTitle = "";
    if (postInfo[1].Length > 50)
        urlPostTitle = postInfo[1].Substring(0, 75);
    else
        urlPostTitle = postInfo[1];
    urlPostTitle = urlPostTitle.Replace(' ', '-');
    return RedirectPermanent(Url.Action("PostRedirect", new { pId = pId, postTitle = urlPostTitle }));
}

    public ActionResult PostRedirect(int pId, string postTitle)
    {
        var postInfo = TempData["PostInfo"];
        if (postInfo != null)
            return View("Post");
        else
            //return RedirectToAction("Post", new { pId = pId });
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("Post", new { pId = pId });
    }
```

In `RouteConfig`:

```
routes.MapRoute("GetPost", "{pId}", new { controller = "Blog", action = "Post", }, new { pId = @"^\d{1,3}$" });
routes.MapRoute(name: "GetPostRedirect", url: "{pId}/{postTitle}", defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "PostRedirect", postTitle = UrlParameter.Optional, reDirect = UrlParameter.Optional }, constraints: new { pId = @"^\d{1,3}$" });
```

Now this approach works sometimes, and sometimes doesn't; usually first time it works fine, second time the browser gives this error:

```
This web page has a redirect loop
```

Sometime if I refresh again it will again work fine, sometime doesn't. And this is on localhost.

On server whenever I deploy this technique and try to access the page, it gives me this:

```
The given path's format is not supported.    

[NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.]
   System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath) +10655581
   System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath) +293
   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList) +109
   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path) +63
   System.Web.InternalSecurityPermissions.PathDiscovery(String path) +29
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_PhysicalPath() +40
   WebsitePanel.IIsModules.SecureFolders.context_OnEnter(Object sender, EventArgs e) +67
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

What might be the reason for this random behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `PostRedirect` action you create loop. If i understood you right, take one action that determine which action will fire. Firstly call this action.

```
public ActionResult PostUrlDetermine(int? pId)
{
   //your logic here

   // if there is any post, generate title, and redirect that post
   return RedirectToAction("Post", new { pId = pId, postTitle = urlPostTitle });

   //else, if there is not such post, redirect not found page.
   // ....

   //or, redirect post page without title, only with id.
   return RedirectToAction("Post", new { pId = pId });
}
```

And Post action:

```
public ActionResult Post(int pId, string postTitle)
{
   //post view page
}
```

Comment: The above solution works fine when the url is like `website.com/12` that is only ID in it, but for the URL which has both ID and title like `website.com/12/my-title` it directly picks up the Route to `Post` method as it matches the argument. Is there a way i can make route `Post` only acesbile from insdie and all both URL reuquest with ID and with ID and title should first goto `PostUrlDetermine` method.